# mvc route rule to map one subfolder to another

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

In asp.net mvc, can you route a request like

```
http://localhost/images/pic.jpg => http://localhost/new/img/pic.jpg
```

Basically I want to map all images which were earlier under a folder called "/images/" to "/new/img/"

Since the urls are already published to third party, I can change the previously published image urls.

Not sure if this can be done using using MVC routing?

Comment: have you tested your app without changing anything...?

Answer (score 0):

Routing ignores resources by default. I think that the ASP.NET MVC routing is for to pair the url's with control/action/parameters.

I think it's much less risk if make a new release from the app1.